# Swift - perform selector with CGSize

Tags: swift, selector

I have this call:

```
myObject.perform(Selector("setCellSize:"), with: CGSize(width: 50.0, height: 50.0))
```

and inside class I have:

```
func setCellSize(_ size: CGSize) {
    print(size)
    self.itemSize = size
}
```

The method is correctly called, but it prints `(0.0, 7.2911220195564e-304)`. What is wrong?

Comment: What is the purpose not to call the method directly (`myObject.setCellSize(...`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`perform(_:with:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/objectivec/nsobjectprotocol/1418764-perform) is a method from the `NSObjectProtocol` and

> Sends a message to the receiver with an object as the argument.

In particular,

> aSelector should identify a method that takes a single argument of type id. For methods with other argument types and return values, use NSInvocation.

If you really have to pass a `CGSize` via this method then you can
wrap it into a `NSValue`:

```
let value = NSValue(cgSize: CGSize(width: 50.0, height: 50.0))
myObject.perform(#selector(setCellSize(_:)), with: value)


func setCellSize(_ size: NSValue) {
    print(size.cgSizeValue)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`CGSize` is not an object. It's a struct. You're printing gibberish passed to your setter. The function is *only* for objects.